# Re-initializing Javascript array inside loop re-initializes it each time through the loop

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code to create an array but if I check array at the iteration ending only contains the last element created. It should have 7 elements because the iteration happened 7 times.

```
for (i = 0; i < intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);// print 7 times
    var dist=euclideanDistance(intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices[i], intersects[0].point);

    map = {v:intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices[i],  d:dist};
    var array=[];
    array.push(map);
}

console.log(array); //only contains one last element
```

Comment: it's because you declare array each time in the for cycle. Declare array outside the for loop.

Comment: I'd suggest you use a technique called "debugging". You do this with a tool called a "debugger". For instance, debuggers let you step through code; they let you put "breakpoints" on code, so the machine will stop and you can examine the state of the world; and they usually have a "variables" window, so you can see the up-to-date values of variables. Do you know about such tools? If not, you should stop programming right now until you've understood them thoroughly. In this case, stepping through your code, watching `array`, would have shown clearly how it was getting cleared each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `var array=[];` before the loop.  As it stands, it's overwriting `array` with a new instance at each pass.

Answer (score 0):

// declaration should go above loop.  lateralus has suggested in comment

```
 var array=[];

for (i = 0; i < intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);// print 7 times
    var dist=euclideanDistance(intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices[i], intersects[0].point);

    map = {v:intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices[i],  d:dist};

    array.push(map);
}

console.log(array); //only contains one last element
```